# Creating generic Swift createOrUpdate method

Tags: ios, swift, generics, core-data

I'm currently trying to create a generic `createOrUpdate` function.

Ideally I want to be able to, on any subclass of `NSManagedObject`, call:

```
Type.createOrUpdate(withID: id) { type in
// Code goes here assigning variable on the object
}
```

Where `Type` is an `NSManagedObject` and `type` is an instance of type `Type`.

This is my current implementation, but my problems are:

1) The `type` returned in the closure isn't of type `Type`,

2) I can't figure out how to create an object of type `T` if one isn't returned by the fetch request.

```
extension NSManagedObject {

    class func createOrUpdate<T>(withID id: String, keypath: String = "uuid", _ block: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: String(describing: self))
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(keypath) == %@", id)

        let context = CoreDataStackManager.shared.stack.backgroundContext

        let updateAndSave: (T) -> () = { item in
            block(item)
            saveContext(context, wait: true, completion: nil)
        }

        do {
            guard let item: T = try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first as? T else {
                // This is where the new item should be created
                // Would then call updateAndSave(newItem)
                return
            }

            updateAndSave(item)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching \(String(describing: self)) with \(keypath) \(id)")
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I now have this in place for creating a new object, which means problem 2 is solved:

```
guard let newObject: T = create(inContext: context) as? T else {
    return
}

updateAndSave(newObject)
```